# Cannot upgrade Chrome 52 to 54 in 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, google-chrome, sudo

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (52.0.2743.116-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
```

This is a pain as I now can't run Selenium scripts, because Chrome doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading and install manually

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

===================OR=================

Update your sources cache again and then try again. I mean

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```